# How can correctly scale a rigged model along with its armature?

Tags: rigging, armature, transforms, scale

I downloaded [this](https://t.co/MJXiFbWsyz) rigged model (from [this](https://twitter.com/PixelUrge) 3D artist). How can I scale the model? When I shrink the model in pose mode the ears and face deformation goes weird. When I scale as an object, the eyes don't scale with the body.

Is there a way to scale the model properly?

Comment: Try scaling the armature object to desired size and apply scale to that first, then mesh.

Comment: @batFINGER, I figured it out I think. The model/rig had an unselectable parent object that the eyes weren't parented to. Parenting the eyes to this master parent fixed the problems when scaling and applying scale.

Answer (score 1):

Probably,your entire mesh is parented to the main armature.
Scaling the armature deforms the object.

The best solution I found in that case is by creating a new empty and parenting the main armature to the empty. Now,scaling the empty scales the model without deformation.

Otherwise,try parenting every single mesh to that empty and scale the empty.